# What would be a good method to variably adjust line thickness after finding edges in an image?

Tags: swift, cifilter

The CIEdges (as well as other CIFilters) are no longer working consistently the same between devices and iOS versions. So I decided to find edges with a convolution filter. Success: I can get a good black and white mask of the images, and let a gradient or solid color show through:

[image: black and white image with edges letting color through]

Problem is, I can't figure out a good way to variably adjust the line thickness. One way I tried was to decrease a version of the source image, and apply the convolution and upscale on top of the black and white camera image. That sort of works, but the lines look jaggy and gross. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
func sketch(with ciImage: CIImage) -> CIImage {

    var sourceCore = ciImage

    var convolutionValue_A:CGFloat = -0.0925937220454216
    var convolutionValue_B:CGFloat = -0.4166666567325592
    var convolutionValue_C:CGFloat = -1.8518532514572144
    var convolutionValue_D:CGFloat = 0.23148006200790405
    var convolutionValue_E:CGFloat = 4.5833334922790527
    var convolutionValue_F:CGFloat = 14.166666984558105

    var brightnessVal:CGFloat = 1.1041666269302368
    var contrastVal:CGFloat = 3.0555555820465088

    // radially symmetrical convolution weights:
    var weightsArr: [CGFloat] = [
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A,
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A,
        convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B,
        convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_F, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B,
        convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B,
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A,
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A
    ]

    let inputWeights:CIVector = CIVector(values: weightsArr, count: weightsArr.count)

    sourceCore = sourceCore
        .applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sourceCore,
                                                        kCIInputSaturationKey: 0.0,
                                                        kCIInputBrightnessKey: brightnessVal,
                                                        kCIInputContrastKey: contrastVal])

    // transforms image to only show edges in black and white
    sourceCore = sourceCore
        .applyingFilter("CIConvolution7X7", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sourceCore,

    let whiteCIColor = CIColor.white
    let whiteColor = CIImage(color: whiteCIColor).cropped(to: ciImage.extent)

    // for some reason, I need to blend the black and white mask with the color white.
    // either CIColorDodgeBlendMode or CILinearDodgeBlendMode seems to work fine here:
    sourceCore = sourceCore
            .applyingFilter("CIColorDodgeBlendMode", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sourceCore,
                                                                    kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: whiteColor])
                                                         kCIInputWeightsKey: inputWeights]).cropped(to: sourceCore.extent)

    // give camera image a black and white Noir effect
    var ciImage = ciImage
        .applyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectNoir", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: ciImage])


    // make solid color
    let color = CIColor(red: 0.819, green: 0.309, blue: 0.309)
    let colFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator")!
    colFilter.setValue(color, forKey: kCIInputColorKey)
    var solidColor = colFilter.value(forKey: "outputImage") as! CIImage
    solidColor = solidColor.cropped(to: ciImage.extent)

    // color is shown through outlines correctly, 
    // and image is black and white
    sourceCore = sourceCore
        .applyingFilter("CIBlendWithMask", parameters: [
            kCIInputImageKey: ciImage, // black and white image
            kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: solidColor, // solid color
            kCIInputMaskImageKey:sourceCore]) // edge work image

    ciImage = sourceCore

    return ciImage

}
```

Comment: FWIW, I've had the same issue when creating a mask with a corner radius and adding an edge to it, all using CIImages. I *think* (not at all sure) it's partly of anti-aliasing and pixels. Maybe you can try to slightly blur the edge lines?

Comment: Blur was one approach I've considered and played around with a little bit, and may be a solution if I can round up the color values to black and round down to white with certain thresholds. CIColorClamp is almost what I'm looking for, except that increases values you match less than a certain amount, and decreases values if above a certain amount. Unless I'm understanding it wrong, I cannot use this.

Comment: When I first read your question I thought of this question an it's answer - I don't think it helps, but it might give you an idea... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927329/cifilter-combination

Comment: Oh yeah I've seen that question before. Thanks, it's sort of what I'm after, but to a higher degree.

Comment: Good luck. If I'm reading what you want correctly (thicker edges with no jaggedness), I think a combination of masking and blurring might work better. If you find something satisfactory, please, post it - I'll gladly upvote it (and probably incorporate it).

Comment: The blurring could help if the edges are hard edges. (entirely black instead of grey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thickness of the edges depends on the width of your convolution kernel *or* the image resolution.

To (dynamically) increase the width of the convolution, you probably need to implement your own custom `CIKernel` since Core Image only supports up to 9x9 convolution kernels. Wider kernels should deliver a smoother result, but are also much more expensive.

You can achieve a similar effect by scaling down the image before you apply your kernel (as you already did) and scale it up again afterward. You could try to use a "smart" upscaling filter like `CILanczosScaleTransform` or `CIBicubicScaleTransform` and play around with their parameters. With `inputC` of the bicubic filter you should be able to control the softness of the result.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I never thought of using the other transform CIFilters. I should see how well they work.

Comment: Note: I cannot find CIBicubicScaleTransform on their list of CIFilters, but they see have a document on the filter itself.

Comment: Yes, Apple‘s documentation is no longer maintained. I recommend going to cifilter.io for reference.

Comment: Wow. I've never heard of that. Thank you.